# How can I retrieve local files with NSURL?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, filesystems, nsurl

I'm here with a question that probably has a really simple answer that I am overlooking... how can I retrieve local files with NSURL? I have this here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var urlpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bpreg", ofType: "xml")
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: urlpath!)!
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}
```

But after it successfully builds it hangs on var urlpath. I've searched around and tried a few suggestions here and other places to no avail. Please help? :(

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are trying to load a file from your file system, not from web.

For creating the `NSURL` you need to use [fileURLWithPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:) class method.

Change your method like:

#### Swift 2

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var urlpath     = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bpreg", ofType: "xml")
    let url:NSURL   = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(urlpath!)!
    parser          = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}
```

#### Swift 3

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let urlpath     = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bpreg", ofType: "xml")
    let url         = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: urlpath!)
    parser          = XMLParser(contentsOf: url)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}
```

---

**Note:** In Swift 3 you can also use the [URL](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url) class to construct the url instead of `NSURL` class. So the above code for constructing url changes to:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlpath!)
```

Comment: Better yet, just use `URLForResource` instead of `pathForResource` as suggested below.  Toss-up which answer is better, both leave something out.

Comment: @MidhunMP Sorry for bugging you again, but I'm having a similar issue with this section (loading a local html file). Maybe you can point out my stupid mistake here? :)

Comment: `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(pageLink, ofType: "html")!)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
        webView.delegate = self
    }`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it myself! :) `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(pageLink, withExtension: "html");
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
        webView.delegate = self
    }`

Comment: @PhilipUlrich: Sorry, I was offline. Happy to hear that you solved the issue

Answer (score 11):

You should use URLForResource(_:withExtension:) instead of pathForResource:

```
let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "bpreg", withExtension: "xml")
```

Answer (score 7):

Your file doesn't exist in your main-bundle yet.

You have to add the file your are using to your Bundle Resource.

So to add it. Go to `App Target -> Build Phases` and check the `Bundle Resource` and add it by drag n' drop.

Comment: I did check this and it was there. Midhun MP had the answer that fixed me up. Cheers!