# Get local URL of downloaded data instead of providing server url

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer

I would like to play a video file in my `ViewController` which is loaded in every page of my `PageViewController`. As you will be able to see I use a plugin called [Carlos](https://github.com/WeltN24/Carlos) to cache the videos (which initially need to be downloaded from a server) so that they do not have to be downloaded every time the user hits a new page. However, I can't figure a way out how to play this downloaded file (`NSData`). Thus, I would really like to know how I can get the URL of the downloaded file so that I can play it using AVPlayer.

### Code (still using URL from server)

```
let omniCache = videoCache.cache

let request = omniCache.get(URL(string: video!)!)

request
    .onSuccess { videoFile in

        print("The file..." )
        print(videoFile)

        //How can I get the local URL here instead of my server url
        if let videoURL = URL(string: self.video!){

            if self.player == nil {

                let playerItemToBePlayed = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL as URL)

                self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItemToBePlayed)

                let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
                playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
                self.controlsContainerView.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)

            }

        }

    }
    .onFailure { error in

        print("An error occurred :( \(error)")

    }
```

Comment: If the file is cached on disk, why not just generate a URL to the local file path and use that/

Comment: @JAL tried it but couldn't figure out how to get the URL and I didn't find a function provided by the library which would do so. :/ Do you know a way to find the local url?

Comment: [How can I retrieve local files with NSURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28419188/2415822)

Comment: But where would I enter my `videoFile` in the code shown in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code of yours:

```
    videoFile in

    print("The file..." )
    print(videoFile)

    if let videoURL = URL(string: self.video!){
```

So in the first line you print `videoFile`, which turns out to be the data of the file. But then you ignore it! You never mention `videoFile` again. Why do you ignore it? That *is* the data, you already have the data. Now play it!

If the data is a file, get its file URL and play it. If it is in memory — it definitely should not be, because a video held entirely in memory would crash your program — save it, and get *that* file URL and play it.

[I have to ask, however, why you are interposing this cache plug-in between yourself and such a simple task. Why don't you just download the remote video to disk, yourself?]

Comment: I know I am not using the data I can't find the local url and don't know how I can play it so that's why I showed what I had until now... I still do not know how the last comment on my question ("How to retrieve local files with NSURL") helps me since I don;t know where I can enter the `videoFile`...

Comment: The library comes with some other functions that make caching a lot simpler in various other cases. In addition to that, it has a memory cache.